# How to do db query that selects only partial columns in Hibernate Panache?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, quarkus-panache, quarkus-reactive

How can I translate below query to Hibernate Panache?
(using PostgresSql)

```
Select t.id, t.name from tableName as t where t.lastName = "abc";
```

For returning all columns it is straight forward.

```
Select * from tableName as t where t.lastName = "abc";
//becomes 
panacheRepo.find("lastName", lastName);
```

Is there a similar way when I want to select only partial columns?

Or if not possible with Hibernate Panache what about with plain Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

With Panache, you can use [query projection](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive-panache#query-projection):

```java
@Entity(name = "Person")
@Table(name = "tablename")
public class Person extends PanacheEntity {
    public String name;
    public LocalDate birth;
    public Status status;
}

@RegisterForReflection 
public class PersonName {
    public final String name; 

    public PersonName(String name){ 
        this.name = name;
    }
}

// only 'name' will be loaded from the database
Person.find("status", Status.Alive).project(PersonName.class);
```

If you are using plain Hibernate, you can specify the select clause in the [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#query-language) or SQL query.

For example:

```java
List<Object[]> results = session.createQuery(
    "select p.name, p.status from Person p", Object[].class)
.getResultList();
```